# Custom WinForms data binding with converter not working on nullable type (double?)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, binding

In my WinForms application I implemented [custom data binding with support for value converters](https://reynaerta.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/ivalueconverter-for-binding-in-winfroms/), similar to WPF.

The sample has a new binding class that derives from `Binding` and allows to attach a custom converter:

```
public class CustomBinding : Binding
{
    private readonly IValueConverter _converter;
    private readonly object _converterParameter;
    private readonly CultureInfo _converterCulture;

    public CustomBinding(string propertyName, object dataSource, string dataMember, IValueConverter valueConverter, CultureInfo culture, object converterParameter = null)
        : base(propertyName, dataSource, dataMember)
    {
        if (valueConverter != null)
            this._converter = valueConverter;

        this.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
        this.FormattingEnabled = false;

        this._converterCulture = culture;
        this._converterParameter = converterParameter;
    }

    public CustomBinding(string propertyName, object dataSource, string dataMember, IValueConverter valueConverter, object converterParameter = null)
        : base(propertyName, dataSource, dataMember)
    {
        if (valueConverter != null)
            this._converter = valueConverter;

        this._converterCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        this._converterParameter = converterParameter;
    }

    protected override void OnFormat(ConvertEventArgs cevent)
    {
        if (this._converter != null)
        {
            var converterdValue = this._converter.Convert(cevent.Value, cevent.DesiredType, _converterParameter, _converterCulture);
            cevent.Value = converterdValue;
        }
        else base.OnFormat(cevent);
    }

    protected override void OnParse(ConvertEventArgs cevent)
    {
        if (this._converter != null)
        {
            var converterdValue = this._converter.ConvertBack(cevent.Value, cevent.DesiredType, _converterParameter, _converterCulture);
            cevent.Value = converterdValue;
        }
        else base.OnParse(cevent);
    }
}
```

There is also the interface `IValueConverter` that is similar to the interface of WPF:

```
public interface IValueConverter
{
    object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
    object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
}
```

With this I'm able to attach an own converter to any (two-way) binding. So far I've built a `TimeSpanStringValueConverter` that allows me to bind a `TimeSpan` field to a textbox as well as a `InvertBooleanValueConverter` to bind the opposite of a boolean field to any boolean property of any control. They work as expected!

Now I want to bind a property of the type `double?` to a textbox `Text` field. For this I wrote this converter:

```
public class NullableDoubleStringValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null ? ((double)value).ToString(culture) : String.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = Regex.Replace((string)value, @"[^0-9" + culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator + @"]", "");
        if (text == String.Empty)
        {
            return null;
        }
        double convertedValue;
        if (Double.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Any, culture, out convertedValue))
        {
            return (double?)convertedValue;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I bind it to the textbox this way:

```
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new CustomBinding("Text", obj, "MyProperty", new NullableDoubleStringValueConverter())); // obj is the data context object
```

When I set a break point in the `ConvertBack` method of the value converter I can clearly see how my string will be converted to a nullable double value after leaving the textbox, successfully. However, instead of my other cases, it will not update the data context object. And if I set a break point in the `Convert` method of my value converter I can see it will retrieve the initial value of `MyProperty` which is null when updating the `Text` of the textbox after leaving it. So, my textbox gets empty after typing any numeric value in it.

**My question is: Why? And how can I make it work with nullable types (`double?`)? If I change the type of `MyProperty` in the data context object to `double` it will accept my changed value.** Unfortunately I need the nullable support. So when leaving the textbox empty I want to store null as well as showing an empty text box, when the value was null.

[Download of Problem Case Solution](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55589036/zzzOther/NullableDoubleStringValueConverterProblem.zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the bug is not in your code, but in the one you have downloaded (`CustomBinding`). Modify constructors to become

```
public CustomBinding(string propertyName, object dataSource, string dataMember, IValueConverter valueConverter, object converterParameter = null)
    : this(propertyName, dataSource, dataMember, valueConverter, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, converterParameter)
{ }

public CustomBinding(string propertyName, object dataSource, string dataMember, IValueConverter valueConverter, CultureInfo culture, object converterParameter = null)
    : base(propertyName, dataSource, dataMember, true)
{
    this._converter = valueConverter;
    this._converterCulture = culture;
    this._converterParameter = converterParameter;
}
```

and the problem will be solved. The essential part is that `Binding.FormatingEnabled` must be `true` in order all this to work (note the last argument to the base call, but you can set it later too). Also note that I removed

```
this.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
```

line. The default value for this is `OnValidation` which is applicable for any control. `OnPropertyChanged` is applicable for immediate update controls like check boxes, radio buttons and non editable combo boxes. In any case, it is better to leave the responsibility of setting this property to the user of the class.

A side note unrelated to the question: You'd better off not stripping the invalid characters and let the exception to be thrown inside your `ConvertBack` method, otherwise you get a weird input values if the user types for instance "1-3"

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var text = value != null ? ((string)value).Trim() : null;
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? (object)double.Parse(text, NumberStyles.Any, culture) : null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Weird that it won't accept the `double?` value with `FormattingEnabled = true`.

Comment: The weird thing I see is that the framework code **does** call `OnFormat/OnParse` when `FormattingEnabled == false`  and does different things. I don't know why `FormattingEnabled` is needed at all, probably for some optimization. Anyway, it is what it is, so the rule is simple to ensure that property is `true` when you want to use format/parse services.

Comment: In fact when `FormattingEnabled == false` it should work, because I cast it the correct way and the return value is totally valid to `MyProperty`. Microsoft uses `FormattingEnabled` to try to convert it by themselves. Seems like we discovered a bug here, because `FormattingEnabled` should not be required at all.

Comment: As I said, it is what it is, and more importantly, is not going to change. We are using this in a big long term project (w/o `IValueConverter`, just custom bindings) from the very beginning (a long time ago) and once realized the need of setting it to `true`, have no problems over all these years.

Comment: To conclude, most probably the truth is contained in the comment of this post http://www.sturmnet.org/blog/2005/10/11/formattingenabled, saying "*It seems that they made a coding mistake and then later have kept that way for compatibility purposes...*". Take care.