# Can you bind property values to variables/data in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

In Flex (AS3) you can do neat things where you bind a property to an expression/variable/object. e.g. `button.enabled = {!obj.name.empty}` It makes for very neat GUI validation amongst other things.

I don't see any such facility in Visual Studio GUI designer but wondered if this sort of functionality exists in .Net/C# and if so, to what extent?

Comment: In what context are you talking about? XAML (WPF and Silverlight) developers are probably used to two way databinding...

Comment: Probably a standard C# Winforms application

Comment: Yes, it involves a [`PropertyManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertymanager(v=vs.110).aspx) and implementing the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.  (It cannot be done to a *variable* which doesn't make sense in c# anyway)

Answer (score 5):

> I don't see any such facility in Visual Studio GUI designer

In fact there is. Select the form/control in the designer, then go to Properties window and expand the (DataBindings) category. You'll see a couple properties there, and more if you click the (Advanced) item.

> to what extent?

It could only bind to a property (no expressions are supported). To make it work, the object providing the property must support property change notification. The standard way is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, but there are also other mechanisms - `IBindingList`implementation providing `ListChanged` event, object providing event named `PropertyNameChanged` for a `PropertyName` etc.

As I mentioned, standartly you can bind only to properties. However, at runtime with some helpers you can really bind to a method or expression. I've already provided examples of doing that in the following threads [Button enable and disable on text changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074979/button-enable-and-disable-on-text-changed-event/33075368#33075368), [Exchange UserControls on a Form with data-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974894/exchange-usercontrols-on-a-form-with-data-binding/32979774#32979774), [Custom WinForms data binding with converter not working on nullable type (double?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691294/custom-winforms-data-binding-with-converter-not-working-on-nullable-type-double/32693534#32693534),  [.Net WinForms design to sync Data and Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888556/net-winforms-design-to-sync-data-and-controls/32290169#32290169)  for a single  item data binding, and my own question [Cross tabular data binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169375/cross-tabular-data-binding-in-wpf) for more complex scenarios.

Contrary to what some WPF-ers say, there are no WF limits when binding to a custom objects/collections. The only limits are when binding to other control properties because control property notification pattern is not strictly followed like in WPF where it is by design.